# SVN: How to check existence of directory, without error message, but with password dialog?

Tags: svn

I have an SVN repo URL like `http://svn/project/trunk/directory`.  How can I test the existence of that directory in the repository, such that an error message is suppressed?  It runs in a script with the SVN command line client on Linux.  I can test with `svn ls URL` or `svn info URL` and check the return value.  But that gives an error message if the URL does not exist:

```
svn: warning: W170000: URL 'http://svn/project/trunk/directory' non-existent in revision 11853
svn: E200009: Could not display info for all targets because some targets don't exist
```

It is okay for the script if that happens, so I want to suppress the message.  But the message is on standard error.  I cannot redirect standard error to /dev/null because there might be a password dialog if a user accesses the repo for the first time.  A --quiet option would be perfect, but that is not supported.  I could do an `svn ls` for the parent directory, but that might not exist too.  The script should not make assumptions about the SVN repo root directory, e.g. for the URL `http://server/data/projects/svn/project/trunk/directory` the repo root is `http://server/data/projects/svn/project`, so I cannot `svn ls` from the repo root down to the directory.  That would also be time consuming if there are many hierarchy levels involved.  Other ideas?

**Edit**: The password dialog used to be on standard error (at least until 1.4), but now (at least since 1.6) the password dialog directs output to /dev/tty (if not under Windows and /dev/tty is available).

**Edit2**: The actual password dialog is not on standard error for 1.6, but the dialog that asks to store the password in plain text still is.  So standard error cannot be discarded for 1.6.  1.8 has both dialogs on /dev/tty.

Comment: Look at the `--non-interactive` option.  Password prompt is suppressed when using it.

Comment: @PatrickQuirk That sounds like the opposite of what the question is asking for (to suppress the error message but **not** suppress the password prompt if it comes up).

Comment: @AndrewMedico Ah you're right, it's in the title!

Comment: @PatrickQuirk I need the password dialog to get access to the repo, I cannot suppress it.

Answer (score 1):

This actually works for me:

```
if svn --username qazwart ls http://svn.vegicorp.com/repo/project/dir > /dev/null 2>&1
then
    echo "It exists"
else
    echo "It doesn't"
fi
```

I still get prompted for my password and I don't see the listing or the error message.

I am on a Mac running 10.10 using SVN version 1.7.17. Have you tried this? If it doesn't work, it'd be interesting to know your OS and SVN version.

If this doesn't work for you, you may have to ask for the password in advance, and then test:

```
read -p"Password for '$username': " password
[[ $password ]] && password="--password $password"
if svn --username $username $password \
        ls http://svn.vegicorp.com/repo/project/dir > /dev/null 2>&1
then
    echo "It exists"
else
    echo "It doesn't"
fi
```

Comment: I tried this some time ago and it did not work, password dialog was on stderr.  That's why I have that "never redirect SVN standard error" rule.  This is valid at least for SVN 1.4.2.  However, in SVN 1.6 and 1.8 this is different and it works to discard stderr, the password dialog is still there.  Time to drop my rule.  Options --username/--password are not necessary.

Comment: The "save plain text password" dialog is still on standard error for SVN 1.6, so it cannot be discarded and my "never redirect SVN standard error" rule is still true.